# Why @media screen rules is overwritten by original css?

Tags: css, screen, media, rules

I'm using @media screen to set specific rules for work on cases, (max-width 1024px). Theoretically these rules should override the CSS originals rules, but this does not occur, only happens if i put !important in each CSS rule that i want to work only for the specific @media screen.

My question is: I'm already using media screen to avoid having to do this. It is normal to have to put! Important in some rules, even using media screen?

There a example:

[image]

Why this happen? If I remove !important from @media screen rules, the @media screen rules doesn't work! This is normal or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The selector `.modal-dialog` is missing from the media query, that makes the original rule has a higher specificity.

Comment: Exactly. Just follow the CSS absolute path and @media screen will work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the css selector in your @media clause is less specific than the non-media one. by making your media version more specific you can get it to correctly override the default styles. look into css specificity for more details, otherwise you will need to use the !important flag.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add as much hierarchy to the non-@media query, and add more specificity to the query within the @media.  This will cause the one you want to run, without using `!important`.

### What not to do:

```
body div {
    width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    div {
        width: 100px; 
    }
}
```

### What to do:

```
div {
    width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body div {
        width: 100px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case the selector .modal-dialog was missing before the selector  .modal-content. So, just follow the absolute css path and is not necessary use !important in attributes, the @media screen will working ok.